# Implementing tensorflow functionality in deeplearning4j

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deeplearning4j

I'm trying to implement the code described in this blogpost with deeplearning4j.

http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/

I'm having problems implementing multiple kernels on the same channel and concatenating the resulting tensors. Is there even a concat function in deeplearning4j? And is it even possible to have different kernels on the same channel?

Tank you in advance.

Comment: Please join our Gitter channel. Skymind engineers are there answering questions: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use our computation graph api:
http://deeplearning4j.org/compgraph